# How do I have exported C# variables appear in the Godot inspector?

Tags: c#, godot

So basically, I'm trying to learn C# and Godot by following a tutorial. During [the section where you code the player](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/03.coding_the_player.html),  I need to have an exported variable (Speed) show up in the Inspector; unfortunately, the variable does not show up. I asked the same question in the official Godot forums but have not recieved a response there yet.

This is an image of the Inspector for my player node:

[image: The Inspector for my player node.]

I tried two things to fix my problem:

1. I copied the code directly from the docs. Here's the code:

```
using Godot;

public partial class Player : Area2D
{
    [Export]
    public int Speed { get; set; } = 400; // How fast the player will move (pixels/sec).

    public Vector2 ScreenSize; // Size of the game window.
}
```

2. I changed the renderer from Compatibility to Forward+.

Comment: Is the C# project building correctly?

Comment: Whenever I build the project, the output in MSBuild reads:
"Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)"

(sorry for late reply btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nvm i figured it out

it was capitalization.

Comment: Adding to this answer as it helped me figure out the issue but wasn't exactly clear on what capitalization was the issue: I had my `Area2D` node named `Player` but my C# script named `player.cs` (even though the class within was `Player`). After I completely removed my `player.cs` script and added a new script named `Player.cs` the property export now works.

Comment: That is an oddly specific requirement. How annoying, Godot should definitely add this to their documentation (which I just read through and didn't see any mention of it)

Comment: If that is the accepted answer, it should also list the steps to fix this. Please improve!
(Luckily there is a comment that leads the way...)